# Get current length of records after filter selection

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

i started using ag-grid, and i need to make some changes in my app, one of them is when the data is loaded in the table, in my footer i show the number of records, but when i start filtering the data in the table, the number of the current lines starts decreasing. can i get the current length of records when filtering the data. Is there a method where a can get the current filteres data?

A example  to achieve is like:

```
Data Loaded:
10/10

Data after being filtered:
7/10
```

Answer (score 1):

use '''api.forEachNodeAfterFilter(callback)''' to iterate through all the rows, counting as you go. mentioned in the api:
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-api/index.php

to know when the row count has changed, listen to the `modelUpdated` event

Answer (score 0):

May be a duplicate of [How to get the number of filtered rows in ag-Grid?]
[1]: [How to get the number of filtered rows in ag-Grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43542998/how-to-get-the-number-of-filtered-rows-in-ag-grid)
The answer there is:

```
gridOptions.api.getDisplayedRowCount()
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use the below code to get the filtered rows count

```
gridOptions.api.getModel().rootNode.childrenAfterFilter.length
```

Comment: @EzLo May I know why it was down voted?. I tried it and it worked.

Comment: @EzLo Can you please mark it as answer if you think it is one of the ways to get the count. Thanks.

Comment: `rootNode` doesnt exist on the model.