# How to get the number of filtered rows in ag-Grid?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ag-grid

I have an [ag-Grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/) with filtering option.

How to get the number of filtered rows without using `forEachNodeAfterFilter` callback?

I want to enable a button only if there is a filtered row, and i don't want to perform a foreach loop in the background every time.

Comment: what do you mean _filtered_? elaborate a little?

Comment: The number of filtered rows, what are filtered by some column (like filter between age 18 and 24)

Comment: would `getGridOptions().api.getModel().getVirtualRowCount()` help you?

Comment: @tanmay be careful with anything with `virtual` in the name there; it refers to a visual concept of nodes being in DOM (not the same as passing filter). https://www.ag-grid.com/upgrading_to_2.x/#foreachinmemory-getvirtualrowcount -- `People were using the rowModel and virtualRow methods to get the rows after sort and filter, which was not great.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
gridOptions.api.getModel().rootNode.childrenAfterFilter.length
```

You should check out what else is available to you under `rootNode`, there are a few arrays that might be useful to you

Comment: rootNode doesnt exist on type IRowModel

Answer (score 17):

What you are probably looking for is:

```
gridOptions.api.getDisplayedRowCount()
```

The actual number of rows after the filtering event is trivially the number of displayed rows.

Comment: This does not returns filtered row, this returns the count of the rows rendered in DOM

Comment: I've combined AG-Grid table of several hundreds of rows with the Filter API, pagination and needed to display the number of all filtered rows (not only the currently dispalyed). Using getDisplayedRowCount() worked fine for me, as i've received the actual number of fitlered rows and not only the rendered rows in DOM.
getDisplayedRowCount() uses rowModel.getRowCount(), which itself uses a filterManager. i don't feel like digging through the screwed up method namings and weak documentation of ag-grid right now. But using getDisplayedRowCount() worked for me.

Comment: getDisplayedRowCount() as the name suggest returns total displayed rows. Initially, it returns all the rows. After filter, it returns filtered rows.

Comment: @LittleXenomorph's answer is the best one. He answered the question perfectly, I guess powercoder23 didn't understand that, cause his comment makes no sense.

Comment: @LittleXenomorph is right. For further information and example, you can look at this comment: https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/2654#issuecomment-440118430

Answer (score 3):

```
onFilterChanged(event) { 
 console.log(gridOptions.api.getDisplayedRowCount());
}
```

In console the count should be the filtered rows.

Answer (score 0):

Use `onFilterChanged()` to access the filtered rows, or the filtered + selected rows. The event passed to [`onFilterChanged()`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-api) can be used like so (example in Typescript React)

(If you need number of filtered just use `ev.api.rowModel.rowsToDisplay.length`)

```js
onFilterChanged = ev => {
  if (ev?.api?.rowModel?.rowsToDisplay) {
    this.setState({ selectedRows: ev?.api?.rowModel?.rowsToDisplay.filter(node => node.isSelected()) });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

We can able to access api using gridRef by declaring part of AgGridReact and then

> gridRef.current.gridOptions.api.getDisplayedRowCount()

```
<AgGridReact
    ref={gridRef}
    columnDefs={columnDefs}
    rowData={rowData}
    headerHeight={35}
    rowHeight={35}
    defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
    onGridReady={onGridReady}
    onFilterChanged={()=> setRow(gridRef.current.gridOptions.api.getDisplayedRowCount())}
></AgGridReact>
```