# Ag-Grid: Compilation Error [ts] Property 'rowsToDisplay' does not exist on type 'IRowModel'

Tags: ag-grid

I am using Ag-grid in my Angular project.

Below is the code:

```
var displayModel = this.gridOptions.api.getModel();
var rowNode = displayModel.rowsToDisplay[params.rowIndex];
```

Error is thrown at `rowsToDisplay`

```
TS2339: Property 'rowsToDisplay' does not exist on type 'IRowModel'.
```

I am able to run it successfully, but just not able to compile.

Did I miss importing anything? I am using v17 of ag-grid community version.

**To share some background**

I use rowsToDisplay, because I want to get the row data by Index, AFTER sorting. the original `gridOptions.api.getRowNode` will not work for me because it does not consider `sorting` which will reshuffle the index numbers...correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: reproduce your issue on plunk or stackblitz so that others can help you easily. also go through how to create [mcve]

Comment: Hi. I've seen a similar problem. Try adding `as ClientSideRowModel` (which gave an error, so hacked it via `as any as ClientSideRowModel`. As any as! Upvote if you find it amusing ;).

Comment: Perhaps relevant for you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43542998/how-to-get-the-number-of-filtered-rows-in-ag-grid/43546786 ?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is not fixed by ag-grid dev team https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/2677
My advice is to remove any type from `gridOptions` property in your component, or set it to any.